# Writing to CSV file from list of Dictionaries with each key having multiple values?

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv

```
results = [
            {"Name" : "Name1", "Issues" : ["issue1", "issue2",    "issue3"]},
            {"Name" : "Name2", "Issues" : "issue1"},
            {"Name" : "Name3", "Issues" : ["issue2", "issue4"]},
            {"Name" : "Name4", "Issues" : "issue4"}
            ]
```

Here is my example dictionary and Below is my code that I am using to write it to a CSV file.

```
writer = csv.DictWriter(filename, results[0].keys(), dialect ="excel",   delimiter=',')
writer.writeheader()
for result in results:
    writer.writerow(result)
```

This is the current output

```
Name,Issues
Name1,['issue1', 'issue2', 'issue3']
Name2,issue1
Name3,['issue2', 'issue4']
Name4,issue4
```

As you see there are times when there are multiple issues per name. I want them to separate them by different delimiters. **For example**

```
Name,Issues
Name1,issue1 issue2 issue3
Name2,issue1
Name3,issue2 issue4
Name4,issue4
```

How do I achieve this? I wanted answer especially with dict writer module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way:

```
for result in results:
    writer.writerow({k:' '.join(v) if isinstance(v, list) else v
                    for k,v in result.items()})
```

`.writerow()` expects a dictionary, the keys and values of which are strings. Since your dictionary's values are sometimes lists, we need a bit of code to convert a list to a string.

Here is an explanation of the techniques I used:

```
' '.join(v)   # Converts the list (v) to a space-separated string

isinstance(v, list) # Decides if (v) is a list or not

' '.join(v) if isinstance(v, list) else v 
              # Evaluates to either v (if v is a string) 
              # or a string (if v is a list)

{k:...for k,v in result.items()} # Creates the new dictionary, where
                                 # all values are strings
```

---

#### EDIT

With the new requirement described in the comments below, I might do this instead:

```
with open('output.txt', 'w') as output_file:
    writer = csv.writer(output_file,
                        dialect ="excel",
                        delimiter=',')
    writer.writerow(["Name", "Issues"])
    for result in results:
        row = []
        row.append(result["Name"])
        if isinstance(result["Issues"], list):
            row.extend(result["Issues"])
        else:
            row.append(result["Issues"])
        writer.writerow(row)
```

Note that we've changed from `csv.DictWriter` to `csv.writer`, so that we can have greater control over the columns.

Comment: Hey, this solves the way I wanted it in the question. But I wanted it to have each issue show as sub columns of  Issue header in excel. Is it possible to do using dictwriter.

Comment: I'll add another code snippet shortly.

Comment: @paris_serviola - I hope the new code helps you.

Comment: Exactly What I wanted. Thank you very very much. :D :D